# ui-route in AngularJS showing empty page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS by following this tutorial: https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial.

I got up to the part right before it says "Creating New Comments". The problem I'm having is that when I click "Comments", a blank page appears with just a horizontal line.

It was my understanding that the title of the post should be on top with the two fake comments. Here's my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flapper News</title>

        <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- ANGULARJS -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>

        <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="flapperNews" style="padding: 50px">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <ui-view></ui-view>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Inline home template -->
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Flapper News</h1>
            </div>

            <!-- Show all the posts -->
            <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2" style="width: 80px;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;{{post.upvotes}}
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <span style="font-size:20px;">
                            <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">{{post.title}}</a>
                            <span ng-hide="post.link">{{post.title}}</span>
                        </span>

                        <br />
                        <span style="font-size: 12px;"> 
                            <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a> l 
                            <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Share</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Form to make new posts -->
            <form ng-submit="addPost()" style="margin-top:30px;">
                <h3>Add New Post</h3>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link" ng-model="link" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit">Post</button>
            </form>
        </script>

        <!-- Inline Posts section -->
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">

            <!-- Display title as header -->
            <div class="page-header">
                <h3>
                    <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">{{post.title}}</a>
                    <span ng-hide="post.link">{{post.title}}</span>
                </h3>
            </div>

            <!-- Display the comment -->
            <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
                {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
                <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">{{comment.body}}</span>
            </div>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

app.factory('posts', [function() {
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };

    return o;
}]);

app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',

    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });

        $stateProvider
        .state('posts', {
            url: '/posts/{id}',
            templateUrl: '/posts.html',
            controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts) {
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;

    $scope.addPost = function() {
        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') {
            return;
        }

        $scope.posts.push({
            title: $scope.title, 
            link: $scope.link,
            upvotes: 0,
            comments: [
                {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool Post!', upvotes: 0},
                {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but no!', upvotes: 0}
            ]});

        $scope.title = '';
        $scope.link = '';
    };

    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
        post.upvotes += 1;
    }

}]);

app.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope', 
    '$stateParams', 
    'posts', 
    function($scope, $stateParams, posts) {
        $scope.posts = posts.posts['$stateParams.id'];
}]);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong for it to display nothing. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Console Errors:

`The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.`

`Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.`

Comment: Seems a path issue or config issue. Can you put a simple plnkr

Comment: Are you getting an error in console

Comment: Never used plnkr before, going to try to get it up there. I posted the errors in the OP.

Comment: @Gary Sorry, can't seem to get anything to show in plnker. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is it a browser issue? When I click "Comments", I still get a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not work because of multiple issues:
1. You are not adding any `id` property in `addPosts()` to your `posts` but expecting it while accessing `posts.posts['$stateParams.id']`.

2. In comments template you are using `post` while you have declared `$scope.posts` in controller.

I have created a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nequbi/edit?html,js,console,output) to add the `id` property and fix other issues and it works now.